# Wordpress not saving after inserting large HTML table

Tags: php, html, wordpress, html-table

I am running into an issue with Wordpress where I have the following repeated 1042 times.

```
<tr>
    <td>number</td>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>place</td>
    <td>points</td>
</tr>
```

This is of course within the proper

```
<table>
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

So when I preview or "update" the page it just loads the page prior to the edits which was a table with about 900 entries.
I do see that when I enter in my data of 1040 entries but truncate it to 1035 it works fine; but, anything past 1035 entries it will, in a way, not save.

Any leads as to what I can look at, or how this may be fixed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really use [WordPress StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Apart from that, you can try things like turning into TEXT mode from your editor, creating a new page (so it gets a new ID) and disabling third party plugins, in order to find out if there is a factor that you hadnt in mind involved into this behavior.